# How to create an array of smart pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers, ns-3

I have created a class, which reference some members as smart pointers, I want to create an array of this class but I get different types of errors

```
class ConnectionType : public SimpleRefCount<ConnectionType> {
public:
  Ptr<Socket> txMstrSocPtr; /// Pointer to Master tx socket
  Ptr<Socket> rxMstrSocPtr; /// Pointer to Master rx socket
  Ptr<Socket> txSlavSocPtr; /// Pointer to Slave tx socket
  Ptr<Socket> rxSlavSocPtr; /// Pointer to Slave rx socket

  //ConnectionType();
  //~ConnectionType();

  void rxMstrCallBack(Ptr<Socket> socket);
  void rxSlavCallBack(Ptr<Socket> socket);
};

Ptr<ConnectionType> ConnectionArray[NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS] = CreateObject<ConnectionType>();
```

it gives me errors
Error   1   error C2075: 'ConnectionArray' : array initialization needs curly braces
        2   IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

Comment: You can't return an array. You can return a `vector<Ptr<ConnectionType>>` though.

Comment: Can you write it in details (Complete syntax), Sorry I'm new to this area

Answer (score 3):

If you know the number of connections that will be returned by `CreateObject` at compile-time (i.e., `NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS` is a compile-time constant) you could use `std::array< Ptr< ConnectionType >, NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS >`.  `std::array` models a raw array most closely of the standard containers and is to be prefer to raw arrays when writing modern C++.  If `NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS` has a size that is determined at run-time you can use `std::vector< Ptr< ConnectionType > >`.  So change to either

```
#include <array>
...
std::array< Ptr< ConnectionType >, NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS > ConnectionArray{ CreateObject< ConnectionType >() };
```

or

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector< Ptr< ConnectionType > > ConnectionArray{ CreateObject< ConnectionType >() };
```

Also, if you weren't already aware, C++11 added support for three flavors of standard smart pointers: `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` (they differ in their ownership semantics) which you might prefer to use over your own homemade smart pointers if they meet your needs and you are able to use a compiler that implements them.

Comment: Thank you but when I use the array it gives an error that it expects a ';' after ConnectionArray in std::array< Ptr< ConnectionType >, NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS > ConnectionArray{ CreateObject< ConnectionType >() };

Comment: @Fouda Replacing your Ptr class with a standard smart pointer, stubbing out a ConnectionType class and changing the initialization syntax the following compiles cleanly: http://ideone.com/eOFc0K

Comment: +1 This solution worked for me. Just wanted to add to this solution for future reference. ' Ptr<ConnectionType> ConnectionArray[NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS] = CreateObject<ConnectionType> (); ' runs fine for gcc version of 5 or lower. For higher gcc versions (which is the obviously the recommended approach), the solution given by @bpw1621 works great.